# Exporting a single scheduled event from chat reliably fails with an error

Tags: bug, chat, export, chat-event

I tried exporting the single event listed in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/33637/my-love-hate-relationship-with-grammar?tab=schedule, but I just get an error page every time. Exporting the entire room schedule (which at present consists of that one event) works fine.